# LCD Display Issue

Tags: arduino-ide

Hi I am a newbie I am trying to test LCD but it always show me a fading boxes It was working before .
connection

LCD p1 - gnd

Lcd p2 - VCC

Lcd p3 - potentiometer middle (10k)

lcd p4 - pin 7 microcon

lcd pin 5 - gnd

lcd pin 6 - pin8 microcon

4 vacant lcd spaces

lcd pin 11- pin9 microcon

lcd pin 12 - pin10 mocrocon

lcd pin 13- pin 11 microcon

lcd pin14- pin 12 microcon

lcd pin 15- 5v

lcd pin 16- gnd[image]

Comment: Try pressing down on the metal surrounding the display, and see if that changes the display. If so you'll have to reseat the display. Probably something wrong with the zebra-strip not making proper contact.

Comment: it keeps blinking and showing boxes when I pressed it thank you very kuch for your response 

Comment: Your pin arrangement makes no sense. You have one pin connecting to the potentiometer, yet the potentiometer doesn't seem to be connected to anywhere else. Check your wiring against one of the many tutorials out there.

Comment: potentiometer connected to gnd and vcc